# Issue generating pdf header after megrating iTextSharp from 5.0.0 to 5.2.1

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

We are using iTextSharp for PDF manipulation and merge.

Recently we have upgraded iTextSharp from 5.0.0 to 5.2.1

We are using `PdfPageEventHelper` class's method `OnEndPage` (overridden in custom class) to write the header.

After upgrading to 5.2.1.0, the iTextSharp generated PDF file does not have the header text we provide. There is no code change. Reverting back to older version (5.0.0), writes the header without any issue.

I am not able to figure it out that what changes in newer version causing this and I don't see anything specific to this in documentation.

Comment: Please post your code. Also, is there any Exception thrown by the code  in your `OnEndPage` method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alexis for your time.

We have figured out the solution and is kind of weird.

We had to change the "FixedHeight" property of the PdfPCell instance from 10 to 20. Also commenting the line to set FixedHeight value (keeping it default, which when I checked is 0.0) did the trick too. So I don't know if the way text get displayed has changed with newer version or its due to any bug.